# por qué los resultado me dan en desorden? c++

Tags: c++

este codigo suma los dos arreglos, el problema está en que los resultados me dan en desorden, cómo puedo solucionarlo? y si hay alguna forma más facil de sumar los vector mejor. muchas gracias :)

edit:

los resultados que me da el codigo es:
22 10 13 12 101 13 7

y debería dar:

7 22 10 13 12 101 13

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int i;
   int v1[]={5,10,7,9,4,99,6};
   for (i=0; i<7; i++){
      cout<<" "<<v1[i];
   }

   cout<<"\n";
   int v2[]={2,12,3,4,8,2,7};
   for (i=0; i<7; i++){
      cout<<" "<<v2[i];
   }

   cout<<"\n";
   int v3[]= {v1[1]+v2[1],v1[2]+v2[2],v1[3]+v2[3],v1[4]+v2[4],v1[5]+v2[5],v1[6]+v2[6],v1[7]+v2[7]};
   for (i=0; i<7; i++){
      cout<<" "<<v3[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: no te puedo dar una respuesta, te recomiendo adjuntar el código que deseas y el resultado que obtienes

Comment: ya actualicé la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En **C** todos los arreglos comienzan con el índice en **0** tu empiezas con el índice en **1** que en realidad es el segundo elemento del arreglo. También para sumar estos arreglos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int v3[7];

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
   v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
}
```

Haces un **ciclo for** y vas sumando los elementos en la posición **i**, fíjate que empiezo en **0** y no en **1**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya se solucionó :)

Answer (score 0):

Acá hay otras dos alternativas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<valarray>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    // Ejemplo 1:
    valarray<int>  v1={5,10,7,9,4,99,6}, v2={2,12,3,4,8,2,7};
    valarray<int>  v3 = v1 + v2;
    for ( int&v : v3) cout << v << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
    
    // Ejemplo 2:
    int v31[7];
    int v11[]={5,10,7,9,4,99,6};
    int v21[]={2,12,3,4,8,2,7};
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        v31[i]=v11[i]+v21[i];
    }
    for ( int&v : v31) cout << v << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Los dos ejemplos imprimen: `7 22 10 13 12 101 13`